# JUnit 5 Before TestFactory Annotation

Tags: java, dynamic, annotations, junit5

I've written a dynamic Test `@TestFactory` in JUnit5, now I've seen I can't do `@Before` for a dynamic Test, referring to
[JUnit 5 User Guide - Writing Test Annotations](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations).

Is there any workaround to do a `@Before` or similar to that before a TestFactory?

Method I want to put in an `@Before` since it's only initialization stuff:

```
public static void initialize() throws Exception{
    buildTest = new XQueryTestHelper();
    buildTest.initialization();
    
    listTestSuiteIdentifier = buildTest.getListTestsuiteIdentifier();
    arrayHdrInbPayTestcases = buildTest.getHdrInbPayTestcases();
    arrayHeaderAndBodyTestcases = buildTest.getHeaderAndBodyTestcases();
    listHeaderAndBodyTestSuites = buildTest.getHeaderAndBodyTestSuites();
    listHdrInbPayTestSuites = buildTest.getHdrInbPayTestsuites();
    
}
```

**Solution:**

Using `@BeforeAll` / `@AfterAll` is possible in a dynamic Test. Referring to
[Improve documentation of DynamicTest lifecycle](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/386)

> **Dynamic Test Lifecycle**
>
> The execution lifecycle of a dynamic test is quite different than it is for a standard `@Test` case. Specifically, there are not any lifecycle callbacks for dynamic tests. This means that `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` methods and their corresponding extension callbacks are not executed for dynamic tests. In other words, if you access fields from the test instance within a lambda expression for a dynamic test, those fields will not be reset by callback methods or extensions between the execution of dynamic tests generated by the same `@TestFactory` method.

Comment: You should use your solution to answer your own question. (Yes, that's possible and totally fine.) You might also want to point to [#378](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/378), which will likely change the integration of dynamic tests into the lifecycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `@BeforeAll / @AfterAll` is possible in a dynamic Test. Referring to
[Improve documentation of DynamicTest lifecycle](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/386)

> **Dynamic Test Lifecycle**
>
> The execution lifecycle of a dynamic test is quite different than it is for a standard @Test case. Specifically, there are not any lifecycle callbacks for dynamic tests. This means that @BeforeEach and @AfterEach methods and their corresponding extension callbacks are not executed for dynamic tests. In other words, if you access fields from the test instance within a lambda expression for a dynamic test, those fields will not be reset by callback methods or extensions between the execution of dynamic tests generated by the same @TestFactory method.

Answer (score 2):

Using `@BeforeAll` or `@AfterAll` is [**not** (yet) possible](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/374#issuecomment-230114255) in a dynamic test.

There are [efforts to implement this](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/694), but it seems that the developers have not yet decided on how it will be done.

I for myself have decided to manually invoke my setup method for the time being, which is pretty ugly.